# Ellipsize - start not working in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pointsTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pointTextView"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:lines="2"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:text="this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence." />
```

Here `ellipsize="end"` is working perfectly, but `ellipsize="start"` is not wroking when no of lines is not 1.

How can I make this work in such TextView with 2 or more no of lines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use `android:ellipsize="start"` with `android:maxLines="2"` (more than one), then it's not possible in android (since API level 1).

**If setMaxLines(int) has been used to set two or more lines, only END and MARQUEE are supported (other ellipsizing types will not do anything).**

See the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hello this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence. "
        />
```

Comment: I want 2 lines to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (android:singleLine="true")

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hello this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence. "
        />
```

Comment: Please read question carefully. -- "How can I make this work in such TextView with 2 or more no of lines?"